# InnoDB: Find clustered index in existing table

Tags: mysql, innodb, clustered-index

Is there a way to explicitly determine the clustered index in an existing InnoDB table. I am aware of the rules for determining the clustered index that are listed in the documentation but I'd like to know if there is a way to explicitly check it in an existing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have read, InnoDB tables always use the PRIMARY KEY or the first non-NULL UNIQUE KEY as their clustered index.

If the table has neither of those, it generates its own clustered index, and calls it 'GEN_CLUST_INDEX'.

```
mysql> create table test.testy ( i int ); -- no eligible clustered index

mysql> select t.name as table_name, i.name as index_name 
  from information_schema.innodb_sys_tables t 
  join information_schema.innodb_sys_indexes i using (table_id) 
  where i.name = 'GEN_CLUST_INDEX';
+------------+-----------------+
| table_name | index_name      |
+------------+-----------------+
| test/testy | GEN_CLUST_INDEX |
+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although the table innodb_sys_tables does not exist on my machine, you pointed me in the right direction. I looked into 'information_schema.innodb_indexes' and found the GEN_CLUST_INDEX there. Is there a table which has the column clustered_index or so for every innodb table?

Comment: What version are you using? The `innodb_sys_*` tables should be present as of MySQL 5.6 and later. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-i_s-tables.html

Comment: I'm using version 8. I guess they renamed them. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-i_s-tables.html

Comment: Yeah, they've done a lot of small changes in 8.0 that break backward compatibility, and I haven't had enough experience with 8.0 yet to keep them in my head.